# Unable to create directory wp-content in WordPress in a windows server 2016

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, windows

I have not been able to upload images to my Wordpress site using the media tool from the Wordpress admin panel. I'm getting the following error.

> “logo512x512.png” has failed to upload.
>   Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2020/01. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I have gone through a ton of solutions to this problem but not one has worked for me.  I am in the windows 2016 server machine. with a MySQL database.  I do not have PhP admin not have a Cpanel.

My ftp is working.  I am able to get themes and plugins without any problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: What are some of the solutions you have attempted? That may assist us in providing additional solutions in a timely manner. For example: if you cannot create a wp-content directory, how have you got the themes and plugins folders working as they are located in `wp-content/themes` and `wp-content/plugins`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is specific to WordPress, and likely fits better on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How did you detemine that this problem is this related to MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible issue is your `chmod` settings for folder `wp-content`. You may need to change `chmod` for the `wp-content` or it's parent directory to allow the creation of any folder/file and child folder/file within that directory.

Depending on which windows application you are using to set the chmod, would determine how this process is undertaken. I use FileZilla and you can simply -

Right Click on `wp-content`, select `File Attributes`, and set `Numeric value: 755`.

[image: FileZilla set cdmod]

In addition, have you considered using a third-party webserver like XAMPP?

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. BUt no.. I am not using and not allowed to installed  the filemozzila.  I will have to go using the Windows server admin tools only.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask on superuser.com ? I believe they are an offshoot of this community and have Microsoft related queries. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with a Google Cloud Engine Instance, with no cPanel, no phpMyAdmin and FTP, on Ubuntu and Apache. And I solved this way:

**1. Define upload folders on wp-config.php**

Open wp-config.php with nano or vim and add the following code

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
```

before this line:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

and save it.

**2. Change owner**

Change to wp-content directory. In my case (use your own path):

```
cd /var/www/html/wp-content
```

Next, change the owner to *www-data*

```
chown -R www-data:www-data plugins
```

Why www-data? In my case, is the name of the apache service account running on my server. You can check the name with:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

that comand returns some like this:

```
www-data  5441  0.0  5.8 566184 34896 ?        S    06:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7753  0.0  5.9 566248 35512 ?        S    09:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9840  0.0  5.7 566160 34320 ?        S    11:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 21068  0.0  6.2 564032 37192 ?        S    18:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 21069  0.0  6.0 563692 35636 ?        S    18:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     21455  0.0  0.1  13208  1036 pts/1    S+   18:44   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
root     31982  0.0  1.1 485904  6872 ?        Ss   Jan03   0:18 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

as you see, root and www-data. Maybe with windows server the account will be different (tasklist? pslist?), i don't know how to get it (I never used windows server, sorry). I Hope www-data works for you.

Finally, make sure uploads folder had the right permissions

```
chmod 755 -R uploads
```

**3. Grant to that user rights to use Wordpress**

To html or public_html folder (in my case /var/www/html, change it for your own path)

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html
```

And voilà. I hope this little guide was useful, or at least, give you ideas to solve it!

Comment: Your command are not very familiar. My environment is Windows server.

Comment: Doesn't the question ask for Windows Server? How can this be the best answer?

Comment: I know you're asking for windows server. But, I hopped reading this steps let you get an approach or idea to solve it in WS. Idk, something like "Ah ok, you change the owner of wp-content" and do it with bash commands. 
If you were expecting a recipe to copy and paste it, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well friends said about putting permissions on directories ...
But on Windows there is a difference between Linux, what I recommend is to put WP-content (just this folder) as chmod 0777 and so in the current upload folder (2020) as chmod 0777.
That should do it. And even if you see that there is advice to always put 0755 I advise you to leave it specifically in these folders.

Make a backup before any changes and I believe it will help you are managing to upload

a good alternative is every month that WordPress creates a new folder for that month then you change the folder permission to 0755 according to the month ended so it helps Ah you have more confidence in the security issue